# Compare date and time value of DatetimeField and now / today

Tags: python, django, datetime

I've added a DateTimeField to my class. I would like to return True if the start_date has been reached. But my implementation is only working for the date part.
Example:

```
Startdate = 2012-06-08 18:00:00
currentdate 2012-06-08 19:00:00 returns False
currentdate 2012-06-09 00:00:00 returns True

from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime

class Game(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('date and time game is started')

    def is_started(self):
        return self.start_date <= datetime.today()
```

So my question is: How can i compare the date and time value of my field and the current date and time?

Comment: I've used the timezone provided by django default settings.py template. That was America/Chicago. I've changed it to my local timezone and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try using datetime.now() instead of datetime.today()

```
class Game(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('date and time game is started')

    def is_started(self):
        return self.start_date <= datetime.now()
```

Comment: Sorry but datetime.now() is not working to. I've changed the time in database to a exhausted value of today and checked it.

Comment: It seems not to be an issue of python code. Seems that datetime.now() returns the wrong time. So i have to investigate how i can tell python to use the server time

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about convenient storage time in my opinion much better store time in ctime integers. With integers you can perform all math operations what you need without headache.

```
import time
time.time()
```